# Cheap laser printer with widely available toners

Tags: printer

I've been using HP LaserJet 1200 for a very long time but now the original drivers are not available and I wanted to find something more suitable for Windows 7/8 & 10.

[image]

My expectations are partially similar to the original printer specs:

- available drivers for Windows 7/8 & 10
- widely available and cheap toners
- monthly page volume: 1500-2000
- print speed: 10+ ppm
- only black print
- at least 600 dpi
- graphics quality printing and network features are not important
- duplex printing is not "must have"
- cheaper than $150 (second-hand items are acceptable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [HP LaserJet Pro P1102w](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-LaserJet-P1100-Printer-series/4110394/model/4110306/product-info)

[image]

Features:

- Drivers compatible with Windows 7, 8, & 10 ([reference](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-LaserJet-P1100-Printer-series/4110394/model/4110306/document/c04658195))
- First party and cheap 3rd party compatible toners ([example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XOXPY8))
- Monthly duty cycle: up to 5000, but recommended volume is 250-1000
- Print speed: up to 19ppm (letter) and 18ppm (A4)
- Only black print
- 600dpi
- Available models with and without wifi (the `w` in the name stands for wifi support)
- Only manual duplex (i.e. no duplex printing)
- Cheaper than 150USD. [It is currently listed on Amazon USA for 94.90USD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0036TGGVO)

[Link to full product details page](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-LaserJet-P1100-Printer-series/4110394/model/4110306/document/c01999607/)

Comment: Any idea how long the fuser tends to last on this thing?  The fuser in my Samsung Xpress M2825 has crapped out after 2 years, and the toner doesn't adhere very well to the paper anymore.

Comment: @alexw I've had it for only a year now so I can't provide first-hand experience, but I've been using it almost daily and without issues.  That said, I did some research in forums and found [this](http://h30248.www3.hp.com/my-sales-guide/competitive/docs/PRODUCTS/Black_and_White_LaserJet/HP_LaserJet_Pro_P1102_P1102W/1xMany/HP%20LaserJet%20Pro%20P1100%20series%20Vs%20Top%207%20Competitors_2.23.2012.Ltr.pdf). Quote: `Samsung users will need to replace a Fuser unit, Pick-up roller and Transfer roller after 30K pages each whereas HP users do not have to replace anything other than toner cartridge`

Comment: Wow!  Not exactly a neutral perspective, but that is a very specific point.  Perhaps this is a known issue with Samsung printers in general.  Thanks!